# Reverse preg_replace - Router

Tags: php, preg-replace, router

I HAVE array with routing:

```
$route = array(
    '/home/news/([0-9])'=>'/home/news/id/$1'
    );
```

And I have script for check request & valide. So I can run:

```
http://mysite.com/home/news/id/4 (run: controller: home, action: news, param id: 4 -> this is defaults)
```

AND

```
http://mysite.com/home/news/4 (run: controller: home, action: news, param id: 4 -> look route array [up])
```

script:

```
$request = '/home/news/id/10'; //example
foreach($route as $r => $key) {
            $r = str_replace('/', '\\/', $r);
            if(preg_match('/^'.$r.'$/',$request)) {
                $request = preg_replace('/^'.$r.'$/i',$key,$request);
                break;
            }
```

So I want now REVERSE all:

```
function createUrl($array) {
  //search in route value and if is ok return key array 
}
```

Example:

```
echo createUrl(array('controller'=>'home','action'=>'news','id'=>4)); //if not exists in route return: /home/news/id/4 but if exists reutnr /home/news/4
```

I sorry for my English :D

Comment: So basically we have to guess the question in here as well as whatever is in `createurl()`?

Comment: Please be more clear in your request, I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply create :

```
function createUrl($route) {
   return $route['controller'].'/'.$route['action'].'/'.$route['id'] ;
}
```

Then if you display information:

```
createurl(array('controller'=>'home','action'=>'news','id'=>2));
```

You will have your expected result.
You can also add a validator inside the function to check the input parameters.